# I get a 0 after the result of my ajax requests

Tags: ajax

Every time I do a particular Ajax request at the end of the result I get a 0. Why am I getting this and is there a way to get rid of it?

The result is good it's just followed by a zero for some reason.

Comment: You will need to add some of your code to get more help

Comment: Put a die() at the end of the script

Comment: I just did. I got tired to looking around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress does that by default at the end of `admin-ajax.php`. It kind of assumes you'll use one of `wp_send_json()`, `wp_send_json_success()`, or `wp_send_json_error()` to communicate your process' state (or at least terminate the script yourself). All of those use `wp_die()` to terminate the script after sending the response. It's sort of a catch-all response.